# I'm using elasticsearch through elasticpress but I keep getting a 403 error, how do I fix it?

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, elasticpress

We have recently switched from using swift-type to elasticpress on our custom wordpress websites for searching our content. We already have elasticpress implemented and working on one website, but it won't work on our other website. On the site that we are trying to convert over, whenever a query is sent out, it returns as a 403 forbidden error. As far as I can tell, the query structure that both the working site, and the non-working site, are sending out are identical. Specifically, the text below is what I am getting in the response section of my network debug tool.

```
Disallowed parameters used in query. Request ID: 739faeeec264db73f6f815ae103771718449980b30574784aa18c722ea76143a.
```

If you want to see this error in action, this plugin is active on our [dev site](https://magazine-dev.byu.edu/). The search bar on the main page is using elasticpress. Typing in two or more letters will trigger the error.

I've tried several things over the last week or so. I've tried removing all of the search fields, thus removing all post-types from the query, but I still get the same error. I've resynced elasticpress many times with different settings and options. I've tried clearing my wp-rocket cache and I've tried clearing the cache through the wp-cli. I installed the wp debug bar plugin along with the elasticpress debugging add-on but strangely, my queries don't show up there. I've tried disabling all of my plugins.